# What's wrong with my Xcode 8? I cant even compile new project?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3

I have two Xcode in my computer. Xcode 7 and Xcode 8. I work with Xcode 7 a lot because some projects cannot be migrated successfully into Swift 3, and I don't have enough time to go over every errors. But when I have new project, I use Xcode 8.

I remember that I have successfully using Xcode 8 to create a project without problem in the past. Today, I create open that project again in Xcode 8, but there are hundreds of errors. I tried to create new project, and compile. I also get lots of errors. Why is this happened?

[image]

EDIT: Anyway, it's resolved now, after I reinstall the Xcode. But that doesn't addressing the problem at all. But I can't reproduce it again now.

Comment: These are the errors related to swift3 which came up on migration. You need to fix those.

Comment: @iYoung no, this is a *new project* under Xcode 8. I'm not supposedly migrate anything when starting a new project, right?

Comment: Are you sure there is no file? Check your project navigator.

Comment: @iYoung the files are just standard of new project: `AppDelegate.swift`, `ViewController.swift`, `Main.storyboard`, LaunchScreen.storyboard`, `info.plist`, and `Assets.xcassets`. I did not touch those files at all since creation of new project. And moreover, the errors are on the Swift's standard classes: `UIScrollView.h`, `UIRefreshControl.h`, `UIPickerView.h`, etc.

Comment: Create new project with new file directory.

Comment: @the_dahiya_boy I just did. Create new project at a whole different path. Still didn't resolve anything.

Comment: You have just created new project and didn't add any file. and x-code giving you the error of files which you didn't have?

Comment: @the_dahiya_boy exactly. well, Xcode has those files, in its internal classes.

Comment: @the_dahiya_boy if you still interested, this is the project: http://www.filedropper.com/zxcv_1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your project is successfully running in my x-code.

[image]

Sometimes, x-code issues may be you face like this one. Now you re-installed the x-code so your project is running properly.

Comment: Yes, I think so. I'm just confused because I haven't open Xcode 8 for a relatively long time, and then it suddenly acting up. I just afraid that this is because I have two Xcode in one Mac, and one can affects another, and maybe this might happen again in the future. I maybe can reinstall, but if I can understand the cause and have the solution maybe I can avoid reinstall Xcode. Thanks for the help.

Comment: X-code 8 have lots of bugs, even in swift suggestion is very slow so sometimes it shows error that I didn't have var while I have create globally. So keep patience with x-code 8.x + swift . :p

Answer (score 0):

When you want to migrate project from swift old version to updated then you face this kind of issues.

Comment: The problem is that this is not migrating project. This is creating *new project* under Xcode 8 and Swift 3 directly.

Comment: check your classes and controller carefully. Perhaps any thing is missed.

Comment: in the end, I solved it by reinstall Xcode 8. It sucks, and will sucks even more if this will be happening regularly.

Comment: this issue is on specific project or same issue for all projects?

Comment: Do you have any pod in project?

Comment: It's File --> New --> Project --> Single View Application. And then immediately compile. I haven't touched any source code yet, let alone add any pods. The project just contains the default files that come with the create new project menu. `ViewController.swift`, `Main.storyboards`, `info.plist`, `AppDelegate.swift`, etc.

Comment: No. The screenshot on question above is actually taken after I compile a newly created project in Swift 3 and Xcode 8, hence the `asdf` random project name.